# Add fade effect to a slideshow

Tags: javascript, html, css, slideshow

I have this slideshow copied from codepen. I have manipulated something to make it my own. Everything works fine but I wanted to add a fade effect and I don't know how. I don't know if it will be adding something to the css file or to the javascript. It would also be good to add the slide effect because the image just disappears and the other appears on top.

index.php

```
<html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
    <LINK REL=StyleSheet HREF="estilos.css" TYPE="text/css">
    <script src="slideshow.js"  type="text/javascript"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="slideshow-container">
    <div class="slideshow-inner">
      <div class="mySlides fade">
        <img  src='imagenes/uno.jpg' style='width: 100%;' alt="sally lightfoot crab"/>    
      </div>
      <div class="mySlides fade">
        <img  src='imagenes/dos.jpg' style='width: 100%;' alt="fighting nazca boobies"/>   
      </div>
      <div class="mySlides fade">
        <img  src='imagenes/tres.jpg' style='width: 100%;' alt="otovalo waterfall"/>   
      </div>
      <div class="mySlides fade">
        <img  src='imagenes/tres.jpg' style='width: 100%;' alt="pelican"/>    
      </div>  
      </div>
      <a class="prev" onclick='plusSlides(-1)'>&#10094;</a>
      <a class="next" onclick='plusSlides(1)'>&#10095;</a>
    </div>
    <br/>
    </div>                
    </body>
</html>
```

estilos.css

```
.slideshow-container {
    /*max-width: 100px;*/
    width:100%;
    position: relative;
    margin: auto;
   
}

.mySlides {
    display: none;
  /*height: 400px;*/
  /*border: solid 1px black;*/
     
}

.prev,
.next {
    cursor: pointer;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    width: auto;
    margin-top: -22px;
    padding: 16px;
    color: #222428;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 30px;
    transition: .6s ease;
    border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0
}

.next {
    right: 0px;
    border-radius: 3px 3px 3px 3px
}

.prev {
    left: 0px;
    border-radius: 3px 3px 3px 3px
}

.prev:hover,
.next:hover {
    color: #f2f2f2;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8)
}

.text {
    color: #f2f2f2;
    font-size: 15px;
    padding-top: 12px;
  padding-bottom: 12px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #222428
}

.numbertext {
    color: #f2f2f2;
    font-size: 12px;
    padding: 8px 12px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0
}

.dot {
    cursor: pointer;
    height: 15px;
    width: 15px;
    margin: 0 2px;
    background-color: #bbb;
    border-radius: 50%;
    display: inline-block;
    transition: background-color .6s ease
}

.active,
.dot:hover {
    background-color: #717171
}
```

slideshow.js

```
var slideIndex = 1;

var myTimer;

var slideshowContainer;

window.addEventListener("load",function() {
    showSlides(slideIndex);
    myTimer = setInterval(function(){plusSlides(1)}, 2000);
  
    //COMMENT OUT THE LINE BELOW TO KEEP ARROWS PART OF MOUSEENTER PAUSE/RESUME
    slideshowContainer = document.getElementsByClassName('slideshow-inner')[0];
  
    //UNCOMMENT OUT THE LINE BELOW TO KEEP ARROWS PART OF MOUSEENTER PAUSE/RESUME
     //slideshowContainer = document.getElementsByClassName('slideshow-container')[0];
  
   // slideshowContainer.addEventListener('mouseenter', pause)
    //slideshowContainer.addEventListener('mouseleave', resume)
})

// NEXT AND PREVIOUS CONTROL
function plusSlides(n){
  clearInterval(myTimer);
  if (n < 0){
    showSlides(slideIndex -= 1);
  } else {
   showSlides(slideIndex += 1); 
  }
  
  //COMMENT OUT THE LINES BELOW TO KEEP ARROWS PART OF MOUSEENTER PAUSE/RESUME
  
  if (n === -1){
    myTimer = setInterval(function(){plusSlides(n + 2)}, 2000);
  } else {
    myTimer = setInterval(function(){plusSlides(n + 1)}, 2000);
  }
}

//Controls the current slide and resets interval if needed
function currentSlide(n){
  clearInterval(myTimer);
  myTimer = setInterval(function(){plusSlides(n + 1)}, 2000);
  showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}

function showSlides(n){
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  //var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
  if (n > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}
  if (n < 1) {slideIndex = slides.length}
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
      slides[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  /*
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
      dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }*/
  slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";
  //dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active";
}

pause = () => {
  clearInterval(myTimer);
}

resume = () =>{
  clearInterval(myTimer);
  myTimer = setInterval(function(){plusSlides(slideIndex)}, 2000);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
opacity: 0;
```

and

```
visibility: "hidden";
```

and not **display: none;** so you can add a transition with CSS for the Fade effect.
I have modified your code and added it to the link below.

https://jsfiddle.net/8hdt4rfu/3/

P.s. If you want a more sophisticated solution, there are some functions, for FadeIn and FadeOut effect, that you can implement and use in your js, such as this: [https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-add-fade-out-effect-using-pure-javascript/#:~:text=The%20fadeOut%20effect%20is%20used,clearInterval%20method%20in%20this%20logic](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-add-fade-out-effect-using-pure-javascript/#:%7E:text=The%20fadeOut%20effect%20is%20used,clearInterval%20method%20in%20this%20logic).

Comment: it works, but i have to modify the  max-height: 300px; min-height: 300px; to 500 so that the whole image is seen. Is there a way to see the whole image without having to adjust that data?